# Increase the precision of a numeric datatype without locking the table

Tags: postgresql, alter-table

I would like to increase the precision of a numeric column on a large tableof  10+ million records. The standard way being `ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mycolumn TYPE numeric(15,6)` will lock the table. This is a highly transactional table. Is there a way to do this without locking the table and without recreating the table, copying the data, and renaming/swapping the tables? I'm currently running a dockerized postgres 9.5

Comment: What is the original column definition? The table will **not** be rewritten when you do not change the _precision_, e.g. from `(12,6)` to `(15,6)` no rewrite takes place.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name shouldn't that be: The table will not be rewritten when you do not change the *scale*. In your example the precision is changing from 12 to 15, but the scale remains 6. User [max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7363226/max) points this out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46678761/increase-the-precision-of-a-numeric-datatype-without-locking-the-table#comment124780214_46678940)

Answer (score 4):

I didn't think changing the typmod required a full table rewrite, but a quick check shows that if you set a breakpoint in `finish_heap_swap`, it does in fact do a rewrite for a cmd like `ALTER TABLE test_numeric ALTER COLUMN x TYPE numeric(8,4)` - at least in 9.5.

---

**Edit**: *a_horse_with_no_name* points out that a rewrite is only performed if you change the *precision*, not the scale. So you can probably do this with a short-lived exclusive lock that won't greatly disrupt operations.

---

Otherwise:

You could potentially cheat and directly update the system catalog, since you know the new precision will be valid for all rows with the old precision. But I'm a bit hesitant, because if it were this simple it's likely PostgreSQL would already do it. I cannot recommend it, but if you want to experiment, test, do some reading, etc, you can start there.

For a table `test_numeric` with column `x numeric(4,2)`:

```
test=> select atttypmod from pg_attribute where attrelid = 'test_numeric'::regclass AND attname = 'x';
 atttypmod 
-----------
    262150
(1 row)
```

If I `ALTER` it to `15,6`:

```
test=> select atttypmod from pg_attribute where attrelid = 'test_numeric'::regclass AND attname = 'x';
 atttypmod 
-----------
    983050
(1 row)
```

(I couldn't be bothered reading the code for the typmod to see how the 32-bit typmod field is decomposed into precision and scale, but you can if you want.)

It *should* be safe to `UPDATE` the `pg_attribute` entry with the new atttypmod. But as I said, do some reading and research first, see if you can find prior discussion of direct typmod updates.

Anything that applies to lengthening `VARCHAR(n)`  will also apply to `NUMERIC`, since both are `VARLENA` storage types internally, and both have typmods where greater values are pure supersets of smaller values. You'll likely find a lot more info on people asking about lengthening `VARCHAR` without a rewrite.

Comment: It seems the rewrite only takes place if you change the precision. e.g. when going from `(8,2)` to `(10,2)` the table is **not** rewritten. But going from `(8,2)` to `(10,4)` it is rewritten.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Good catch!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for that! I've confirmed that in my testing. Though I think that documentation might need to be a little more clear. That's not how I read it. Oh, well.

Comment: Not sure if it matters but for folks who were confused like me I think a_horse_with_no_name is mis-stating. The example presented by them (and what I see substantiated in the strong_migrations gem) is that the rewrite only takes place if you change the SCALE NOT PRECISION.
You can see how the data type is defined in the docs- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-numeric.html#id-1.5.7.9.7.4 as compared to their example (second value is Scale, first is Precision)